# ReactiveX: calculate frequency of distinct elements in an Observable

Tags: java, scala, reactive-programming, rx-java, reactivex

I have an `Observable<String>`. I would like to turn this into a `Map<String, Int>` which tells me the number of occurrences for each distinct string.

The observable contains ~1 billion elements, out of which 1000 are distinct (therefore storing the entire dataset in the RAM is not an option). Currently I iterate over the `Observable` and update a `HashMap`. I also make sure to observe on the same thread to avoid race conditions. However, getting the element frequency should be inherently easy to parallelise, hence it would be nice to make use of that.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Since the data source is sequential and the update operation O(1), I'm not sure you'd gain much by going parallel.

Comment: @akarnokd The data source is calculated on multiple threads and with my current method I have to synchronise which slows things down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` instead of maintaining the `HashMap` by yourself. `groupBy` will create an `Observable` for each key, and you can subscribe it on a different Scheduler. E.g.,

```
public class KeyCounter {
    int key;
    long count;

    public KeyCounter(int key, long count) {
        this.key = key;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "key: " + key + " count: "  + count;
    }
}

@Test
public void foo() {
    Observable<Integer> o = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 2, 1);
    o.groupBy(i -> i).flatMap(
        group ->
            group.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).countLong().map(count -> new KeyCounter(group.getKey(), count))
    ).subscribe(System.out::println);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```